# How to create a particular 3D variant of MatrixPlot?

Tags: plotting, matrix, visualization

Does anybody know an elegant way to implement a matrix plot of the following form in Mathematica?

[image: Example of desired 3D Matrix plot for a Matrix Y_ij]

Where $Y_{ij}$ is just an matrix of complex numbers (the index $a$ just counts different matrices, ignore it for this purpose). Assume that `Y[[i,j]]` contains the relevant data.

I can do all of this brute force by assigning the $x$ and $y$ coordinates (matrix entry locations) of points to the absolute value of the entry as $z$ coordinate but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way?

The purpose of this is quite similar to the Mathematica feature [`MatrixPlot[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPlot.html) but that produces a 2D and color-coded image, wheras for the purposes of data visualization in my project images like the one above might be slightly more useful.

Comment: Have you tried `ListPlot3D`?

Comment: As @Rahul notes: `ListPlot3D[Abs[mat]^2, BoundaryStyle -> Red, MeshStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> None]` seems to do what you want.

Comment: I've played around with ListPlot3D but like I said what I came up with seemed unnecessarily brute force and required some pre-processing of the data. Your code sample seems promising, thanks.

Comment: Timon G., have also a look at the `InterpolationOrder` option of `ListPlot3D`. I think what you are looking for is essentially bilinear interpolation:  `ListPlot3D[Abs[mat]^2,, Mesh -> Dimensions[mat] - 2,InterpolationOrder -> {1, 1}]`.